# SWITCH_SELECTION is not working with SelectLayerByLocation_management

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

```
 import arcpy,sys
 sdeConn = r"Database Connections\\Test.sde"
 muniLoc = "Municipalities"
 luLoc = "Land_Use"
 tempLoc = "tempMuniLuRatio"
 arcpy.env.workspace = sdeConn

 try:
    print "MakeFeatureLayer_management lu_lyr"
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(luLoc, "lu_lyr") 
    prematchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lu_lyr").getOutput(0)) 
    print "MakeFeatureLayer_management muni_lyr"
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(muniLoc, "muni_lyr") 
    print "SelectLayerByLocation_management COMPLETELY_WITHIN"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lu_lyr", "COMPLETELY_CONTAINS",muniLoc,"","SWITCH_SELECTION")
     postmatchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lu_lyr").getOutput(0)) 
    if prematchcount == postmatchcount:
        print "SelectLayerByLocation_management DID NOT WORK"
    else:
        print "SelectLayerByLocation_management LOOKS GOOD"
        if arcpy.Exists(tempLoc):
            print "Delete_management "
            arcpy.Delete_management(tempLoc)
        print "CopyFeatures_management "
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('lu_lyr',tempLoc)
 except Exception:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print(e.args[0])
```

So I add

```
if prematchcount == postmatchcount:
```

to see `SWITCH_SELECTION` worked or not.

every time it returns same result as source feature `class`.

Have I miss anything in my *code*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Change this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lu_lyr", "COMPLETELY_CONTAINS",muniLoc,"","SWITCH_SELECTION")
```

To this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lu_lyr", "COMPLETELY_CONTAINS",muniLoc)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lu_lyr", None, None, "", "SWITCH_SELECTION")
```

---

**Details**

`GetCount_management` and `SelectLayerByLocation_management` are working as documented.

From [Get Count](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm):

> If a selection is defined on the input, the count of the selected rows is returned.

From [Select Layer By Location](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm):

> SWITCH_SELECTION —Switches the selection. All records that were selected are removed from the selection, and all records that were not selected are added to the selection. The **select_features** and **overlap_type** parameters are ignored when this option is selected.

Let me explain what your code is doing and why it is correct.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(luLoc, "lu_lyr")
```

You create a feature layer with no selection. Let's say the `Land_Use` feature class has 42 features in it.

```
prematchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lu_lyr").getOutput(0))
```

Since no selection is defined on `lu_lyr`, all features in the feature class are counted, and `prematchcount` now equals 42.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lu_lyr", "COMPLETELY_CONTAINS",muniLoc,"","SWITCH_SELECTION")
```

Since you're using `SWITCH_SELECTION`, `COMPLETELY_CONTAINS` and `muniLoc` are ignored, and the selection is simply switched. Before this call, zero features were selected. This call switches the selection so that all 42 features are selected.

```
postmatchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lu_lyr").getOutput(0))
```

Since a selection is defined on `lu_lyr`, only the selected features are counted. The previous line selected all 42 features, so `postmatchcount` now equals 42.

```
if prematchcount == postmatchcount:
```

True. They are both 42.

Your fix depends on what you want to do, which you did not say. My guess is that you want to select all features in `Land_Use` that do not completely contain a feature in `Municipalities` and copy those selected features to `tempMuniLuRatio`. If so, make the change described at the top of this answer. If not, please edit your question to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Gary, thank you for your reply, I'll take time to read and fix it.